# Form entry lost after second value submit

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms

I am new to angular and using reactive form when submitting a form, the value captured by `this.first.name` replace/update with new one on my next entry in form. How can I add more values when my function is run, instead of replacing old value?

```
first = {
    name : ''
  }
      onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.netForm);
        this.first.name = this.netForm.value.Name;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it an array to collect all the values that come in.

```
first = {
    names : []
}

onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.netForm);
    this.first.names.push( this.netForm.value.Name );
    this.labForm.reset();
}
```

and output it like this for example

```
<span *ngFor="let name of first.names">
  {{ name }}
</span>
```

Comment: No, I mean when user run the `onSubmit()` again, it will replace first value e.g first time I entered Nofel, and that shows but when I enter Basti in field, it replaces Nofel with Basti, whereas I need both as much as I want to add

Comment: @Nofel I changed my answer, to make it more precise I would need to know hoe this.first is initiated.

Comment: I get the error now saying `[ts] Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string'.
any` It is initialised as an empty object in class

Comment: @Nofel so make it an array `first.name = [];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158239/discussion-between-nofel-and-basti).